# Binary struct to a random record in a file and back again

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, struct

I have a data structure I want to read and write to random records in a binary file. I have tried using NSFileManager/NSFileHandle and could not figure out how to convert my data types to what it likes to see as a data stream to a file. I have tried pread and pwrite with similar issues. I think fread and fwrite would be most suited and again have had similar issues. My code is crappy and not worth posting.

EDIT - just to show how syntax challenged I am, this is how I tried to cast the structure to an NSString and then to NSData so that I could write it with NSFileManager (got EXC_BAD_ACCESS error???):

```
NSString *d = (__bridge NSString *) &b224;
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:d];
```

Please help, I am new to C and I have spent a day so far learning about this issue but no success. To make matters worse I think the endians were shooting arrows at me. I can't find any tutorials on doing this and hope someone out there can point me in the right direction. The structure covers seven 32 bit int32_t integers and is padded so that each record is 224 bits or 28 8bit bytes.

Is it OK to use int types in struct for integers only a few bits long?  This seems to work and even seems to preserve the sign bit as long a I give it an extra bit for it.

I want to use this in Objective C code for iPhone app, using Xcode 5.

Speed and efficiency in doing this is a major concern.

EDIT - The file will end up having hundreds of thousands of records and random individual records may need to be updated very minute or two.

RESOLVED - see comments.  To create NSdata *d to send to file:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *) &b224 length:28];
```

To put data from NSData *r, that was read from file, back into structure:

```
[r getBytes:&b224 length:28];
```

NOTE 1 - It does seem to be very important to keep the bit fields grouped in groups of 32 and not have any fields overlap any 32 bit boundary, not sure why and I will leave that for the experts to figure, at least I got it doing what I want when no field overlaps a boundary.

NOTE 2 - Make sure you never put a value outside the bit fields range into it, they don't seem to be truncated when you do this, they shift all the other bits and your record gets corrupt.

Thanks!!, Carmen

```
struct bfbits{
   int lat:28;
   BOOL real:1;
   BOOL inuse:1;
   BOOL inter:1;
   BOOL turn:1;

   int lon:29;
   BOOL units:1;
   BOOL onleft:1;
   int free2:1;

   int who:26;
   int free3:6;

   int day:16;
   int heading:9;
   int free4:7;

   int limit:7;
   int trucklimit:7;
   int altlimit:7;
   int warnft:10;
   int free5:1;

   int uses:16;
   int rejects:16;

   int starthr:5;
   int endhr:5;
   int beginday:4;
   int finishday:4;
   int beginmonth:5;
   int finishmonth:5;
   BOOL daynight:1;
   BOOL weekday:1;
   int free7:2;
};
struct bfbits b224;
```

Comment: This is a scary amount of bitfields (and a scary amount of variables to have in a single struct).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly - is `cout << bfbits.lat` what you're trying to do? (Where `cout` could instead be a pointer to an open file, and `lat` is the member of your `struct`)

Comment: I could easily split it into 7 32bit structs but I thought it would be faster read/writes and easier to refer to in code in one.  Is my logic wrong?

Comment: Ollie, I was trying to read and write the whole struct at a time I will check out your suggestion although I tried before to use commands that use std:: and had issues adding the include in my Xcode project.

Comment: You should only need to `#include <iostream>` for `std::cout`. You can't do "all at once", say by looping through as the member types differ. I say you can't - if you want to do it this way, look up `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`.

Comment: The BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT looks a little beyond my conceptual grasping abilities right now.  I could change all the BOOLs to ints and then only have one type of data members in the struct if that helps.

Comment: so your struct should have 7 32 bit members and the entire struct should be 224 bits or each of the 7 members should be 224 bits?

Comment: You can't just cast an arbitrary pile of bits into an ObjC object. You can easily create an `NSData` object from binary data, however, using `+[NSData dataWithBytes:length:]`

Comment: Thats great! NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *) &b224 length:224]; Give me an answer so I can give you credit.  I just need to convert the other way now too (for a read) but I think that should be straight forward. Carmen

Comment: Actually I think that line should read: NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *) &b224 length:28];

Comment: And the reverse conversion, to put a file record into b224, is that once you have read the file record into an NSData *r, simply do [r getBytes:&b224 length:28];  Thanks Josh!!!!

Answer (score 0):

A few points

- The general idiom is "make it work first, then worry about making it fast"
- Reading files from disk rarely results in a single 32bit value being read. There is very likely a huge amount of data being pulled every time you hit I/O. How much depends on your device, and O/S. But its going to be *much* larger than your entire file at this point.
- Additionally, an entire cache line will be pulled every time you read from the I/O buffer, this will also be larger than a single 32 bit value.

What I'm trying to say is, using bit-fields for all this isn't going to help you much and will probably complicate things. also: Modern cpu's and bit fields are... not exactly friends. Modern CPU's are designed to do operations the size of your registers, so using non static masks or doing variable >> and << will be very slow. If you really must use bitfields, use constant masks.

Additionally, its likely that you're nicely arranged data isnt working due to alignment. Due to the above cache reads, its quite common that your data structures will be padded to the nearest N bytes to preserve alignment for cache access. so any 5bit structures will really end up being padded out to whatever the alignment happens to be (probably 8 bytes).

The best thing to do, would be to pull in your file data as a unsigned char*, and then look at the buffer's memory contents. then, compare that with the memory contents of the pre-populated structure that you prepared early and see how the alignment of various things looks.

At this point. I'd just make everything an int32, and see if you can just pull the whole lot straight into memory that way. If that works, then your attempt at packing data is causing you problems.

Comment: Great info! The file will end up having hundreds of thousands of records and random individual records may need to be updated very minute or two.  With that in mind, it should not matter if I get a lot of extra bytes on a read as long as I only 'see' my 224 bits.  Obviously I only want the 224 bits of a record affected on a record write. Not sure how the data padding you mention could affect the reads and writes of 224 bits of data, would they not get stripped as they are read and only the relevant 224 bits given to me? Carmen

Comment: The kind of access pattern you're describing is why we developed databases. So why not use one? Perhaps SQLITE or something in-memory which deals with various locking conditions?

Comment: I have used SQL databases for other things on another platform but this is only single user, single program access to the file and I do not want the overhead of a DB if I can do what I evision.